# Android pinging an web service address

Tags: android, web-services, localhost, ping, inet

I want to implement a feature that will ping an address of web service and if it returns true then the application will run through web services otherwise it will use the database of the device (sqlite).

I wrote the code,

```
public boolean lookfunc()  
{  
     String name1=name;  
     boolean reachable=false;
     try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.56");
            reachable = address.isReachable(3000);
            System.out.println("address.isReachable(3000)"+reachable);

     }   
     catch (UnknownHostException e){  
              System.err.println("Unable to lookup ");  
     }  
     catch (IOException e){  
              System.err.println("Unable to reach ");  
     }  
      catch(Exception e1){System.out.println("Exception raised");}  
      return reachable;  
}
```

The address 192.168.1.56 is pinging in command prompt but here in code it always return false.

And web service url is : http://192.168.1.56:8080/WIP/services/ConnectionDAO?wsdl, here also this throwing UnknownHostException.

Comment: You do know 192.168.x.x is reserved for private subnets, right?  Most external network infrastructure will refuse to pass on traffic to that range, because it's assumed to be either mistaken or some kind of attack.  So for example, you phone on its mobile data plan cannot contact your cable/dsl router.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a point in pinging. Try to download from the web service, and use the database if that fails.

Comment: Thanks Kaj. But still in this case if services are stopped it throw exception and stop at that instant. i have tried to do this way but after exception it doesnt keep the execution but stop instantly.

Comment: Huh? Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Catch the exception and continue with your processing.

Comment: i am already catching exception but at runtime, the screen becomes blank and in logcat it display message "Launch timeout expired, giving up wake lock" and java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out.

Comment: You should execute your logic in separate thread, or with an asynch taks. Don't execute it in the ui thread.